# mod_rewrite & file_get_contents problem

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, file-get-contents

I'm having this .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase "/d/IT2 Tryggheim/it prosjekt 2011 - 2. termin/css/"
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.(css|less))$ rewrite.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

And inside the css folder I'm having an rewrite.php file that looks like:

```
#$file = $_GET['file'];
$file = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/' . $_GET['file'];

if(file_exists( $file ))
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    # TODO: add code that parses the $content variable
    echo $content;
}
else
{
    echo "Weeeee! The file (<i>$file</i>) does not exist! :D <br /> <br />";
}
```

This is all tested on Wampserver. If I go to this path directly it works:

http://localhost/d/IT2%20Tryggheim/it%20prosjekt%202011%20-%202.%20termin/css/deafult.css

If I however have a file, one directory up which have the following HTML, in it, it doesn't work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/deafult.css" />
```

Or, it doesn't work unless I disable the .htaccess, then it works. So how do I get the php to load the file?

**Alternatives for $file that I have tried and which is not working**

```
$file = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/css/' . $_GET['file'];
$file = '/css/' . $_GET['file'];
$file = 'css/' . $_GET['file'];
$file = './css/' . $_GET['file'];
```

**Other stuff I tried**

- Tried using include instead of file_get_contents
- Tried hardcoding in the filename ('deafult.css') instead of using the $_GET variable

Comment: You make it unnecessarily complicated. Why don't you write down the original problem? You could get a simple solution.

Comment: The original problem: I want css and less files to be parsed by a php file. The less files is to be convertet to css. And both css and less is supposed to be compressed. Also I might want to replace some of the less variables inside the less file with other values based on some user settings (chosen by which color palette the user want to show the webside in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this in the top of the rewrite.php file and now it works! :D

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rewriterule is looping.

Since you pass the name of the CSS file to your PHP script, you end up with something like:

.../css/rewrite.php?file=test.css <- it matches your rewriterule again.

It would be easier if you removed rewrite.php from the css folder

Comment: Even if I change the rewrite rule to:

RewriteRule ^css/(.*)\.(css|less)$ rewrite.php?file=$1 [NC]

And add . '.css' to the $file - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script doesn't get the directory `css`, so it is looking for /default.css instead of /css/default.css ;-)

Comment: $file = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/css/' . $_GET['file'];

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you didn't make a typo? http://localhost/d/IT2%20Tryggheim/it%20prosjekt%202011%20-%202.%20termin/css/deafult.css <-- deafult.css instead of default.css

Comment: Well, deafult.css is indeed an typo, however it is an typo which I have both in the filename of the css file and in the referring of the css file from the HTML.

Comment: Instead of using file_get_contents, try `include`